# CSX getting current submission instance

Tags: c#, csx

I'm trying to get current submission instance in csharp csx script. I need to invoke script method with reflection:

```
using System.Reflection;

void Foo()
{

}

var foo = MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.GetMethod("Foo");
foo.Invoke(???, null);
```

I cannot use `this` keyword, as it's not available in scripting context:

```
error CS0027: Keyword `this` is not available in the current context
```

Trying to invoke `foo.Invoke(null, null)` fails because `Foo` is not a static method.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: Don't think it is possible ('this' refer to an instance of a class which is not the case here). What are you trying to do? 
Anyway - if you wrap it all in a class it would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it's not the most elegant solution, it's possible to get instance using expression trees.

Anywhere in your script place following code:

```
using System.Reflection;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

void Stub() { }

object GetInstance(Expression<Action> expr)
{
    var invoke = (MethodCallExpression)expr.Body;
    return ((ConstantExpression)invoke.Object).Value;
}

var This = GetInstance(() => Stub());
```

Now the `This` variable contains current instance of Submission, and one can safely call `foo.Invoke(This, null)`